# Laravel - RuntimeException - Could not scan for classes inside "app/tests/TestCase.php"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've been using Laravel to display a custom blog for a month or so now and it's been working perfectly.

I just took a look at my site and it's saying:

```
/vendor/symfony/security/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Having looked in the folders the location of the above file is actually:

```
/vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

but I haven't changed this?

If I try and run `composer update` I get this error:

```
root@server [/laravel]# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/tests/TestCase.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Any ideas what's causing this or how I should go about fixing / debugging it?

Comment: do you have a `app/tests/TestCase.php` file on your production server? If not - you should remove it from `composer.json` (or put the file back there)

Comment: Perfect that's fixed it, not sure why it changed though.

Comment: Cool - I've added it as an answer for you.

Comment: if my answer below has solved your problem, please accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do you have a `app/tests/TestCase.php` file on your production server?

If not - you should remove it from `composer.json` (or put the file back there)

Comment: I had this problem, as well, and this fixed it.
Apparently during my setup of Codeception, it added an entry in the classmap autoload in composer.json for the file "app/tests/TestCase.php".
Removing this classmap entry allowed composer to run normally.

Comment: Make sure to remove tests and their dependencies from production.
Use ```--no-dev``` when executing the composer command.

Comment: Doing `composer install --no-dev` suppose to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem facing in Laravel 5.1, But is resolved now.
Solution is : only test directory and files are in root directory structure.
Other wise we removed in composer.json.

Note: We should be maintain for the core Directory structure and files on frameworks, due to feature migration and enhance the project and testing purpose.