# Error in composer update laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying do composer update in CMD but catched this error

```
could not scan for classes inside database which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

which is not the cause and is not much information about the meeting, which can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be related to the auto-loading of your `composer.json` file. It seems that the `database` folder is not being found by composer. Did you check if the folder exists?

Also, googling the issue, there are plenty of questions opened about this, pointing to pretty similar issues as yours:

- [1st. Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347503/laravel-runtimeexception-could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-app-tests-testca)
- [2nd. Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424381/laravel-4-2-composer-install-error-could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-app-model/29425250)
- [3rd. Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647375/laravel-4-2-composer-install-error-could-not-scan-for-classes)